Unable to generate maven-cucumber reports
My maven project build is success with warning as shown below. Terminal console shows, it is about to generate cucumber report and

Unexpected error happened
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No JSON report file was found!

terminal console log report:

Here is my pom.xml plugins
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <!--          <mainClass>cucumber.api.cli</mainClass>-->
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
        <environment>${env.USR}</environment>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
      <properties>
        <configurationParameters>
          cucumber.junit-platform.naming.strategy=long
        </configurationParameters>
      </properties>
      <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-cucumber-reports</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <jsonFiles>
            <param>**/*.JSON</param>
          </jsonFiles>
          <projectName>${project.name}</projectName>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
          <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
          <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
          <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
          <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
          <buildNumber> ${project.build.version}+1</buildNumber>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>17</source>
      <target>17</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>


Please don't post pictures of errors, code, logs or other text. Instead, copy the original text to your question.
